# How open cookies in Google Chrome

Tags: python, cookies

for learning purposes, I am making a program to transfer cookies between browsers, but I have a problem with google cookies, I know where they are, but I can’t open them through python .. because there is no extension just cookies .. when I open the properties, it says that file format

I try get path, and open path with sqllite - don't work

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Agree with the comment above - Can you post a copy of your code, so we can better help you?